# In Naïve Bayes, why do we estimate Pr(W|H)*Pr(H) instead of Pr(W)

Tags: naive-bayes

This wikipedia article describes spam filtering using Naïve Bayes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering

It says `P(S|W)` is given as `Pr(W|S)*Pr(S) / (Pr(W|S)*Pr(S)) + Pr(W|H)*Pr(H))`.

However, one could also get `P(S|W)` by estimating `P(W)` instead.

Most textbooks simply say it's unnecessary to estimate `P(W)` which I get, but one could also say it's unnecessary to estimate `Pr(W|H)*Pr(H)`. Why is it that estimating `Pr(W|H)*Pr(H))` is preferred?

**Example**:
If we use [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-naive-bayes-classifier-how-it-works-e229e7970b84),

The "correct" estimation for `P(yes|rain, good)` is `0.143` because

```
P(rain|yes) * P(good|yes) * P(yes) = 1/5 * 1/5 * 5/10 = 0.02
P(rain|no) * P(good|no) * P(no) = 2/5 * 3/5 * 5/10 = 0.12
P(yes|rain, good) = 0.02 / (0.02 + 0.12) = 0.143
```

Whereas one could also estimate it as follows which gives `0.042` instead:

```
P(rain|yes) * P(good|yes) * P(yes) = 1/5 * 1/5 * 5/10 = 0.02
P(rain, good) = P(rain) * P(good) = 3/5 * 4/5 = 0.48
P(yes|rain, good) = 0.02 / 0.48 = 0.042
```

My question is, why is the former preferred, even though they seem to make similar approximations

Comment: `Pr(W) = (Pr(W|S)*Pr(S)) + Pr(W|H)*Pr(H))`

Comment: Approximating `Pr( W1, W2 | S) = Pr( W1 | S) * Pr( W2 | S )` vs. `Pr( W1, W2 ) = Pr( W1 ) * Pr( W2 )` is not the same though, no? @J.Delaney

Comment: What you wrote is an assumption of conditional independence. Not sure how it is related to the question

Comment: What I mean is, by assuming conditional independence, one could estimate `Pr(W1,W2|H)` or `Pr(W1, W2)`, both of which can be used to estimate `Pr(S|W1, W2)`. But the two ways can result in a different estimate thanks to the conditional independence usually not being true. It seems that estimating `Pr(W1,W2|H)` is always preferred, and my question is, why is that - why is that better than estimating `Pr(W1, W2)`? @J.Delaney

Comment: I can't see which "two ways" you are referring to.  Try clarifying your question

Comment: Added edit, hopefully this clarifies @J.Delaney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can immediately see that the second calculation is incorrect because probabilities should add to 1, namely you should always have `P(yes|rain, good) + P(no|rain, good) = 1`. But this is not the case in your second calculation, so clearly it makes no sense.

The reason for this is that *conditional* independence does *not* imply independence. Naïve Bayes assumes that the features (e.g. road condition & weather condition) are conditionally independent given the target variable,   so for example `P(rain,good|yes)=P(rain|yes)*P(good|yes)` but this does not imply that `P(rain, good) = P(rain) * P(good)`, hence the inconsistency in your calculation.

Comment: I can satisfy `P(yes|rain, good) + P(no|rain, good) = 1` by simply estimating `P(no|rain, good) = 1 - P(yes|rain, good)` though. And to your second point, you are saying one assumption does not imply a different assumption, which is true, but it doesn't answer why the assumption NB makes is better than assuming raining and road condition being independent. Both are wrong assumptions, so shouldn't they be equally correct?

Comment: The problem is that in the second case you are assuming *both* conditional and total independence. The two together in fact imply that the features are independent of the target variable (notice that total independence is a much stronger assumption). This is clearly not what you want, and it makes the calculation inconsistent since you are using estimates that violate your own assumptions (as evident by the fact that you can get different results by performing the same calculation in different ways).